# Get Developer Api Key for the Google Picker api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

I am trying to find where in the google developer console I can get my developer api key. In the snipet from an example they have below it is referred to as the developer key and the browser key. Could anyone help me with this?

```
 // The Browser API key obtained from the Google API Console.
 // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
 var developerKey = 'xxxxxxxYYYYYYYY-12345678';
```

Comment: If you've got a project and subscribed to APIs all of your credentials are here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Answer (score 1):

- Go to [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) left hand side bottom click on credentials
- click the blue button at the top create credentials
- chose the first one API key.

The term developer key is an api key it is an old term that has not been used for years i suspect you are following an old tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to register with Google and they will give you an API Key. You have to register a project and all that and then you can get your key in there.  Start here: https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=picker&credential=client_key&pli=1